# Auto-center div content horizontally in last row if there are 1 or 2 divs present

Tags: html, css

All right so I have a bit of an odd request to try and fulfill. I have a page that has a listing of divs, inside of which are an image and a link. Each row has 3 divs max. Sometimes, though, the last row may have just 1 or 2 divs. What I need to try and do is set things up so that if the last row only has 1 or 2 divs, then those divs need to be centered horizontally within their row.

Is this something that is possible? Would I need to use JavaScript/jQuery to count the number of divs in the final row? Or could I do this all with just CSS?

Here is how the divs are setup right now:

```
  <div class="About-Categories clearfix">
    <div class="About-Category clearfix">
        <img src="[image url]" class="image">
        <a href="#">[link text]</a>
     </div>
     <!--Additional About-Category divs go here as needed-->
  </div>
```

There could be any number of About-Category divs, but the css is setup to ensure that there are only 3 About-Category divs within the width of the page (until a screen size of 460px is reached).

CSS as it is now:

```
.About-Categories{
  text-align: center;
}
.About-Category{
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 33%;
  &:nth-of-type(1){
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

Comment: setting `text-align: center` for the parent and `display: inline-block` for child elements will give you the desired results.

Comment: something like this might be helpful for you: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/constructing-css-quantity-queries-on-the-fly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#wrap { 
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
}
.tile {
    width: 198px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you display the divs as `inline-block`, they'll respect the text-align attribute. In combination with a wrapper sized to fit three divs, you should get the result you're looking for.

Example:

```css
#wrap { 
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
}
.tile {
    width: 198px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div><div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is I can't set the parent div or its children to a fixed with because it messes up the responsive css....

Comment: @SaraDeJaneiro You could, by all means, just swap the pixel-widths for percentage values, but I feel like that would be a pain down the road (3 boxes side-by-side get a lot smaller on an iPhone than a computer). Perhaps you could just use hardcoded pixel-widths on the actual "tiles" and a 100% (or whatever) width on the wrapper? That way, they'll stack up nicely next to each other on wide screens but collapse into a single column on smaller screens.

Comment: That could work...but the "titles" themselves have been set to float: left so they stay at 3 per row until the smallest screen size. This seems to be messing up the use of text-align: center for the parent div and the display:inline-block for the children.

Comment: Why are they floated? If you want them to stay to the left, you could just not use `text-align: center`, since `text-align: left` is the default value.